# C funny for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, pointers, c-strings

Here's a snippet one of my coworkers used in some legacy code I am using now. The code runs and the for loop's body gets executed only five times. I can't figure out the reason why this doesn't execute until n which is 100.

Does anybody have an explanation? This would be really useful since my company is keeping this code and I have to help maintain it. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i, n = 100, *d=&n, *s=&n;
    for (i = 0; i < n && (*d++ = *s++); ++i)
    {
        printf("i = %d; n = %d; *d = %p; *s = %p;\n", i, n, d, s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is terrible, hideous code.  Maybe just rewrite the loop so that it makes sense?

Comment: It's not only terrible code, it's *invalid* code that will cause [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Nodedesign Now it is very interesting what is the name of the company that hires such programmers?:)

Comment: There is nothing funny about that code.

Comment: I suspect that is not the actual code, and that the actual code was a routine like `strncpy` that copied up to `n` characters from a string `s` to an array/pointer `d`, passed as parameters rather than initialized to point to `n`.

Comment: If the code is really as you've presented it, *why* is they company keeping the code? What is the stated purpose of the program? If, instead, you've adapted the actual code to a short example, please go back and make sure that your example really reflects the code in actual use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presented program has undefined behavior because after the first assignment that does not make sense

```
(*d++ = *s++)
```

pointers `d` and `s`  point outside the object `n` and dereferencing such pointers after their increments results in undefined behavior.

I can imagine the following similar approach that is valid for copying strings as shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s1 = "Hello World!";
    enum { N = 20 };
    char s2[N];

    const char *p1 = s1;
    char *p2 = s2;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N && ( *p2++ = *p1++ ); i++ )
    {
        printf( "%*.*s\n", ( i + 1 ), ( i + 1 ), s2 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
Hello 
Hello W
Hello Wo
Hello Wor
Hello Worl
Hello World
Hello World!
```

However in this case instead of the loop it is much better and simpler to use the standard C function `strncpy`.

The only advantage of the loop is if it is required also to get the number of copied symbols excluding the terminated zero.

Comment: I'd like to add that ASCII value of NULL is zero in C. So as soon as end of string is encountered, (*d++=*s++) will return 0 making the condition false. This will terminate the loop